# SailsJS v0.10 Lookup model by many association

Tags: node.js, associations, sails.js, waterline

I've been enjoying the new Sails relationships in v0.10, but my biggest challenge currently is looking up models by their associations. If I were to have populated a manual association, say, an array of IDs, this would be pretty easy. However, I can't seem to find the right way of handling the lookups with a Sails association.

I've provided some sample code that outlines two models, a Company and a User. Companies can have many Users, and a User can have only one Company. This is a pretty straight forward one-to-many relationship, and the goal is to find all Companies that match a User ID.

```
## Company.js
name:
  type: 'string'
  required: true

users:
  collection: 'User'
  via: 'company'


## User.js
company:
  model: 'Company'
  required: true

last_name:
  type: 'string'
  required: true

first_name:
  type: 'string'
  required: true


## Lookup Users by Company ID of '2'
User.find(where: company: 2).exec(console.log)

# Result
# [] - Array of users matching that company ID


## ---- The Problem / Question ----
## Lookup Companies by User ID '1'
Company.find(where: users: contains: 1).exec(console.log)

# Result
# Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error:
# error: column company.users does not exist
# Details:
# { error: 'E_UNKNOWN',
#   summary: 'Encountered an unexpected error',
#   status: 500,
#   raw: 'error: column company.users does not exist' }
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on the best way to handle this lookup!

Comment: Looks like your models are not correctly defined:
http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models

Comment: They are, it's just the same message as when an attribute literally doesn't exist, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of querying "all companies whose list of users contains #1", you're trying to do a subquery, which Waterline does not currently support.  Furthermore, it's a slightly silly example since every user can only have one company, so you should only ever expect one result.  In any case the correct method would simply be to look up User #1 and *populate* its company:

```
User.findOne(1).populate('company').exec(function(err, user) {
    console.log(user.company);
});
```

I'll leave it to you to translate that to Coffeescript ;)

To find all of a company's users, you'd do something similar:

```
Company.findOne(123).populate('users').exec(...)
```

You can *filter* the populated results, but it's not the same as a subquery:

```
Company.findOne(123).populate('users', {where: {id: [1,2,3]}}).exec(...)
```

This would get you company #123 and populate its `users` array *only* with users with ID values of 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I ended up moving forward with a solution along the lines of what you mentioned first, with finding the filtered model type then populating the goal model.